# Activerecord Connection Pool Optimization for Highly Cached System

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, activerecord, amazon-rds

I have a rails activerecord project that has been scaled out to serve approximately 60-100k requests per minute. We use AWS and it takes about 5 xlarge c4 ec2 instances to serve this many requests. We have optimized the system to serve 99.99% of those requests off of a redis cache rendering our mysql DB barely used.

This is great and all but we keep running into connection limits for mysql. Amazon RDS apparently limits the number of connections we can have and it seems silly for upping our RDS instance size just so that we can have a larger number of sleeping connections. We literally profiled the RDS server and it maybe gets 10-50 queries a day depending on how many times we update the system.

**Is there any way to keep the activerecord connection pool from reserving connections?**

We tried simply lowering the connection pool and it helped in lowering connections, but then we started getting:

> (ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError) "could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds

What I would like to achieve is for the rails project to stop trying to pre-allocate connections and only open then up when they are necessary. I'm not well-versed enough in the rails framework and activerecord to understand how the system is reserving connections and why we are getting ConnectionTimeoutErrors even though the application isn't even making any DB calls.

Comment: I'm no expert but this article could be of interest for you https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections . What app server are you using ? e.g Puma, Unicorn etc

Comment: Also , I would check if I could just increase the pool in database.yml , I'm not sure that it's your database not being able to accept the connections but maybe Rails is doing this

Comment: did all that already. Thanks though @Joel_Blum. I'm using puma.